# I cannot import excel file to Microsoft acess

Tags: excel, ms-access

When I go to **External Data** tab and select **Excel** option, I can export data from there but cannot import it.
I get this form where there is no way to import
[image: IMG1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]Just go to external data tab, then in the top left corner there is a button "new data source". Click this and then choose "from file" and then you can choose "Excel"

Comment: You are awesome!

Answer (score 0):

You can use VBA to do the same, or more, like importing data into Access, from multiple Excel files.

```
Sub TryThis()
Dim strPathFile As String, strFile As String, strPath As String
Dim strTable As String
Dim blnHasFieldNames As Boolean

' Change this next line to True if the first row in EXCEL worksheet
' has field names
blnHasFieldNames = False

' Replace C:\Documents\ with the real path to the folder that
' contains the EXCEL files
strPath = "C:\Documents\"

' Replace tablename with the real name of the table into which
' the data are to be imported
strTable = "tablename"

strFile = Dir(strPath & "*.xls")
Do While Len(strFile) > 0
      strPathFile = strPath & strFile
      DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, _
            strTable, strPathFile, blnHasFieldNames

' Uncomment out the next code step if you want to delete the
' EXCEL file after it's been imported
'       Kill strPathFile

      strFile = Dir()
Loop

End Sub
```